# What technique should be used to make video tutorial for BS(CS) students?

Tags: student-motivation, struggling-students, active-learning

For students, there are a lot of different tasks which are given by their lecturer. 
One of the task is that to make a professional video tutorial of specific topic which is related to Computer Science. And then upload that video on you tube to give help to others students. But there is one problem how to make a good video tutorial which should be understandable to every one who want to watch and get benefit from it. What technique should be applied during making video?

Comment: I've voted to close this, because the "for BS (CS) students" part of the question seems incidental to the problem of _making a video tutorial_ and perhaps suited to another SE network site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a lot of good suggestions for you. However, if you really want a *professional* quality video, you need to use a professional. The videos deployed by Open University UK, for example, are prepared in the BBC studios with large (large) budgets. I assume you have to get by with something less.

Different platforms have different tools, but there are video/audio capture applications for most of them. You might also need to use various camera and microphone setups, including wearable microphones, in order to capture what you want.

But you will still have a big problem. One is that it is difficult to capture audio in such a way that it can be heard and understood by your audience.

A bigger problem is the time (and software) needed to edit what you capture so that it makes sense to the viewer. Pacing and sequencing are very important.

The key to success for do-it-yourself, however, is to use repetition and feedback to learn how to do it, the same way that students learn. Make something with some tools and then get someone to give you feedback on it. Repeat and repeat again until you get it right. Eventually you will make something you like. Or decide to hire a professional.